# HTML5: W3C vs WHATWG. Which gives the most authoritative spec?

Tags: html, html-parsing, w3c

I'm in halfway trough an html parser and found html5 defined **explicitly** the rules of thumb for parsing *ill formed html*. *(And I used to infer them from DTDs, sigh)*

I love that fact, but I know well that html5 isn't finalized yet (also I wonder if it ever will) and that it isn't developed by the W3C, but by the WHATWG.

Searching for the spec I need I'm presented with:

- 8.2 section of the **W3C** *TR*
  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing

or

- 11.2 section of the **WHATWG** *web-apps/current-work*
  http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/parsing.html

If it wasn't for the section numbers I would induce those are simply the same. But the different numbering makes me wonder. *Which version is, supposedly, the most authoritative?*

WHATWG seems to have more sections, and to have been *added to* since W3C uploaded its candidate recommendation.

Will W3C update to the WHATWG version?
Or will they stick to their current candidate until it gets to the official recommendation status?

**Which html5 spec are we poor devils supposed to follow, when in doubt?**

Comment: Pragmatically, the WhatWG might be the one to follow as the main browsers developers follow their rules, and not the W3C ones.

Comment: https://archive.is/64uAd#selection-1007.450-1007.594. And 
https://archive.is/64uAd#selection-937.290-959.7 , https://archive.is/64uAd#selection-999.507-999.738. And 

https://archive.is/64uAd#selection-983.252-983.495, 
https://archive.is/64uAd#selection-937.197-937.263,  https://archive.is/64uAd#selection-1033.267-1033.449 . And https://archive.is/64uAd#selection-991.367-991.504. And https://archive.is/64uAd#selection-999.740-999.878

Comment: 1. https://www.infoq.com/news/2014/10/w3c-ignores-whatwg 2. https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2016/05/11/my-url-isnt-your-url/ 3. http://html5doctor.com/interview-with-ian-hickson-html-editor/ 4. https://plus.google.com/+MichaeltmSmith/posts/QdGfrgtP6Eg 5. https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-archive/2014Apr/0034.html 6. https://www.cbsnews.com/news/html-5-google-microsoft-apple-and-adobe-fight-to-rule-the-web/ 7. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHATWG

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It depends on who you ask. Really. The politics of this are ugly. And to make matters worse, the specifications aren't fully stable yet. I would have thought that the two specifications would be largely the same in their parsing sections since [section 1.1.1](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/introduction.html#how-do-the-whatwg-and-w3c-specifications-differ?) which lists the differences does not mention parsing. But then I did a web diff and I saw that there are subtle differences in the text. I would say that if you are actually implementing the specification to talk to the players involved about any differences you see between the specs, using the public mailing lists. Anyway, I am sorry I can't give you a clear cut answer.

Comment: "The politics of this are ugly" is such a pain, we're finally getting some traction and html5 is being seen as _the_ platform for the future but we're still being confused and held back by political bickering. Getting there though :)

Comment: I would not call it bickering - The two groups have different opinions, and we're waiting for the dust to settle - for them to agree and swallow compromises and arrive at a joint spec. This kind of process is natural. I never understood why people are so opposed to political processes - yes, sometimes they are counterproductive, but more often than not, just natural. It's been going on for millennia, and software industry is not going to be the one standing out for lack of political "bickering" ;-)

Comment: -1 this answer is really outdated in 2018 - whatwg is de-facto the only standards body that has been taken seriously in the last few years and it's the one all the browser vendors participate in.

Comment: To be truthful, this question and answer would be closed today as 'primarily opinion based'. Anyhoo, my personal opinion today is that the dust has more or less settled in favor of the WHATWG, at least for HTML.

Answer (score 78):

Always choose **WHATWG** over W3C, no exceptions.

*Anne van Kesteren*, (a WHATWG member who was a major contributor to the the HTML specification prior to the WHATWG and W3C versions diverging, and who remains a major contributor to the WHATWG specification) describes the current situation between WHATWG and W3C as follows on his [blog](https://annevankesteren.nl/2016/01/film-at-11):

> The **W3C** has forked the **[WHATWG]** HTML Standard for the *n*th time. As always, it is pretty disastrous:
>
> - Erased all Git history of the document.
> - Did not document how they transformed the document. Issues of mismatches have already been reported and it will likely be a long time, if ever, before all bugs due to this process are uncovered, since it was not open.
> - Did not discuss plans with the wider community.
> - Did not discuss plans with the folks they were forking from.
> - Did not even discuss plans with the members of the W3C Web Platform Working Group.
> - Erased the acknowledgments section.
> - Erased the copyright and licensing information and replaced it with their own.

## 2019: The war is finally over

On May 28th, 2019, W3C and the WHATWG have signed a agreement to collaborate on a single, authoritative version of the HTML and DOM specifications.

According to [W3C's statement](https://www.w3.org/blog/news/archives/7753), the two parties have come to the following terms:

> - W3C and WHATWG work together on HTML and DOM, in the WHATWG repositories, to produce a Living Standard and Recommendation/Review Draft-snapshots
> - WHATWG maintains the HTML and DOM Living Standards
> - W3C facilitates community work directly in the WHATWG repositories (bridging communities, developing use cases, filing issues, writing tests, mediating issue resolution)
> - W3C stops independent publishing of a designated list of specifications related to HTML and DOM and instead will work to take WHATWG Review Drafts to W3C Recommendations

Comment: W3C reeks of incompetence. is Tim Berners-Lee still at the helm?

Answer (score 34):

Biased answer from an editor of WHATWG HTML here. Hopefully the facts can speak for themselves though.

The WHATWG Living Standard should be considered authoritative. It is [constantly worked on](https://github.com/whatwg/html/pulse) by a large community of contributors, including all browser vendors. No browser vendors implement according to W3C HTML; for some such as Firefox and Chrome this is a matter of publicly stated policy.

The WHATWG Living Standard is constantly receiving bug fixes and new features. For more information on this model of spec development, which more closely matches modern software development practices, see [What does "Living Standard" mean?](https://whatwg.org/faq#living-standard).

Unfortunately, the W3C sometimes copies and pastes our work onto their own website, and puts their own logo on it, and changes the names of the editors, and such. They do this for a variety of reasons, one of the largest of which is face-saving for the sake of their paying member companies ([example of them stating this](https://github.com/w3c/charter-html/issues/14#issuecomment-108606731)). What's worse, they like to release "versions" (like HTML "5.0", "5.1", etc.) which are just outdated versions missing modern bug fixes and features that clog up search result pages, causing confusion like this very question. We are currently [tracking the confusion caused by these forks](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Fork_tracking), of which HTML is only one.

You can track their progress on the copy-and-paste job in [their issue tracker](https://github.com/w3c/html/issues?q=is%3Aissue+label%3A%22WHATWG+Port%22) or in commits such as [this one](https://github.com/w3c/html/commit/8a55cddf019d3d71a8152929716612902d9b5190). It's a fun game to spot the bugs they introduce while doing this copy-and-paste job, as they generally do not read or understand the content they are copying, leading to widespread errors and inconsistencies.

Comment: Aren't you guys too concerned about what people think of you, over than, uhm... concerned with dishing out usable standards in a format that someone, noy payed 24/7 for that, can follow?

Comment: I think it's unreasonable to expect (data) consumers to constantly play catch up with a moving target. There's a reason why definite, specific, milestoned standards exist, and it's not because people weren't smart enough to do it differently.

Comment: @Domenic, And if truly every browser is for whatwg and none is for w3c, then exactly who are these people behind the w3c html standard? Who are supporting them?

Comment: Largely it is W3C management, who are concerned about not getting paid membership dues if they admit the reality that nobody pays attention to their fork.

Comment: "closely matches modern software development practices", okay, but software still has releases with versions. I don't see why the HTML standard cannot. You could still "release early, release often", but with version numbers, optimally semantic ones.

Comment: Modern software doesn't really have versions; instead it uses practices like continuous deployment. Sometimes versions do exist as part of the distribution channel artifact (e.g. app stores or other native app auto-update mechanisms), but this is platform-specific.

Answer (score 7):

OK , I eventually came to my own conclusion and I'm gonna share it.

**I will follow the W3C version: blindly.**

*Politically speaking* it's not a simple decision. Let me explain.

> I was extremely sceptic about w3c, and I possibly even *hated their
>   guts* during the whole **XHTML** debate/debacle. I saw the rise of
>   **WHATWG** as the arrival of our pragmatical saviours: people that
>   openly admitted that HTML can't be made into a stiff, rigorous XML-derived language, while *the whole internet* bothers *nigh* about it.

So given this point of view I should go with the WHATWG spec, shouldn't I?

No. Why?
**WHATWG doesn't establish official versions**. I kind of wish they did, but they don't.

They feel versions are too rigid for their...let's say *hip* attitude.
They instead have only a *live standard*.
*(and track implementation status of any single feature by major browsers)*

But I'm not a major browser, I'm a small implementer, **I cannot refer to a live standard**.
Well, not unless I go crazy over it and *release constantly*, like there's no tomorrow.
*(that's sort of what is happening with firefox and chrome)*

So over neverending frenetic madness, I have to choose sanity. And W3C offers polished and numbered versions of the spec. **And I can claim to conform to one of those version**.

Comment: Claiming to conform to "one of those versions" is rather useless, as only whatever is latest matters for real world interoperability. And as explained in a different answer, it's impossible to trust what the W3C is publishing since they're just badly copy-and-pasting (indeed, with all the mistakes that come with that) someone else their efforts.

Comment: I agree with Anne, but the "Living standard" is so vendors-driven that following changes for a simple web developer is a really complex task. If they would just provide a simple way to track changes, I'd totally agree...

Comment: @Anne, “only whatever is latest matters for real world interoperability”: the opposite, interoperability requires stability, that's why we often refer to **standards**. Interoperability cannot be achieve when things change all the time.  Think about UNIX before its standardisation …

Comment: Things do not change all the time, but minor changes are required to reach convergence between implementations. And often old snapshots do not contain those minor changes and are therefore a bad reference as they don't reflect reality. Standards need maintenance just as much as software does.

Comment: WHATWG seems to be on the agile train, whereas W3C is on the waterfall train. The agile train is faster.... for a little while. The waterfall train is much slower... but it won't bust a side rod around a tight turn. The waterfall train also has the benefit of knowing where it is going in advance.

The W3C principles built the Web. I fail to see any reason besides upstart ego to change that practice.

The only reason people carp about XHTML is because they like to write crappy markup.

Comment: @ZJR from a 2018 perspective, only WHATWG matters and it's the only standards body anyone is taking seriously. You should change the accepted answer to Domenic's probably.

Comment: OMG look what literally just happened https://github.com/w3c/dom/issues/175#issuecomment-380534425

Comment: @ZJR Why do you say so? I agree with there only being living standard, but can't you confirm to that day of living standard, and why do you want  to confirm, things change and that is the best way in case of daily evolving need and uses, we cannot wait for years for new features. That is just my opinion, I am open to yours.

Answer (score 4):

https://www.w3.org/html/ gives a clear answer to this old but still actual question:

> **https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/ is the current HTML standard.
>   It obsoletes all other previously-published HTML specifications.**
>
> As announced at
>   https://www.w3.org/blog/2019/05/w3c-and-whatwg-to-work-together-to-advance-the-open-web-platform/,
>   the W3C and the WHATWG signed an agreement to collaborate on the
>   development of a single version of the HTML and DOM specifications:
>
> https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/ is the single version of HTML
>   being actively developed https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/ is the single
>   version of the DOM specification being actively developed. For further
>   details about the W3C-WHATWG agreement, see the [Memorandum of
>   Understanding Between W3C and WHATWG](https://www.w3.org/2019/04/WHATWG-W3C-MOU.html).

The part *"obsoletes all other previously-published HTML specifications"* means that https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/ is considered obsolete.

P.S. The URL from the question, http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing, redirects to https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, try to match the behavior of actual browsers. That's all that actually matters.

In general, WHATWG is probably more current than W3C, though it may include more things that browsers don't support (yet).

You can think of W3C as taking snapshots of WHATWG at given points in time, stabilizing them, and then hardening them, never to be changed.

- W3C HTML5 was finalized 28 October 2014.
- W3C HTML5.1 was finalized 1 November 2016.
- W3C HTML5.2 is currently in its "Working Draft" and probably won't be finalized until 2019.

Comment: this defeats the very purpose of having standards

Comment: It isn't stabilizing them. It is blindly copying pasting them often with bugs.

Answer (score 2):

**[Feb, 2023]**

This issue seems to be closed definitively as WHATWG abandonment of W3C has forced them (W3C) to concede as per this [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web):

> In 2009, the W3C conceded and abandoned XHTML[24] and in 2019, ceded
> control of the HTML specification to the WHATWG.[25]