# Why does Document.prototype.getElementsByName exist in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementsbyname

As I know,`getElementsByName` is a function defined in `HTMLDocument`,and `HTMLDocument` inherits from `Document`,and `Document` inherits from `Node`.

So why I can see `Document.prototype.getElementsByName` in Chrome but not Firefox?Does not Chrome implement DOM2 spec?

Comment: Why would it be *wrong* to provide it even on `Document`? They *do* follow the spec, as it is available on `HTMLDocument`.

Comment: Link to the spec is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-71555259

Comment: [This discussion](http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2011-August/032878.html), though dated, seems to be related.

Answer (score 3):

> Does not Chrome implement DOM2 spec?

Yeah, probably not. I'd guess they at least implement [DOM 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#i-Document), if not a [more](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/) [current version](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/) :-)

However, those don't define a `getElementsByName` either. So how did they get this? It is actually specified in HTML5 ([WHATWG](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dom.html#document)/[W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-document-object)) on the `Document` [partial interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#dfn-partial-interface):

> The DOM specification defines a Document interface, which this [HTML5] specification extends significantly […]

And at http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/dom.html#documents-in-the-dom I found the note

> Because the HTMLDocument interface is now obtained using binding-specific casting methods instead of simply being the primary interface of the document object, it is no longer defined as inheriting from Document.

So the specification details of these interfaces are still in progress, and varying. <s>Notice that browsers are not even supposed to export any kind of `DocumentPrototype` - the specs do only define *interfaces*, not the exact EcmaScript binding representation of them.</s> [WebIDL does](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#es-interfaces).

So Chrome does follow the newer specs (but still has some `HTMLDocument`?), while Firefox implements an older version. However, it only really matters that these methods *do exist* on every `window.document` - not how they got there :-)

Comment: And what the relation between w3c.org and whatwg.org on HTML spec?Which should I read?Little confuse

Comment: [*The politics are ugly*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825713/html5-w3c-vs-whatwg-which-gives-the-most-authoritative-spec). Actually, there shouldn't be much difference, [but nobody knows](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/introduction.html#is-this-html5?).