# Are results of hasOwnProperty() tests for DOM elements standarized?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I was surprised to discover that in Firefox console:

```
> document.mozPointerLockElement
> null
> 'mozPointerLockElement' in document
> true
> document.hasOwnProperty('mozPointerLockElement')
> false
```

Whereas in Chrome console equivalent `hasOwnProperty()` test returns true:

```
> document.webkitPointerLockElement
> null
> 'webkitPointerLockElement' in document
> true
> document.hasOwnProperty('webkitPointerLockElement')
> true
```

Does HTML standard specify which properties of a document should be direct and can be reliably tested with `hasOwnProperty()` or are all such tests implementation dependent and not portable?

Comment: It's hard to know conclusively that something doesn't exist, but I'd be very surprised if that behavior was covered by a standard. The `.hasOwnProperty()` function is a JavaScript thing, and the DOM really has nothing to do with JavaScript.  They don't even use JavaScript syntax to describe the APIs.

Comment: In _FireFox_ it's on `proto(proto(document)); // DocumentPrototype`, I believe there is very little spec-wise saying how _Host Objects_ such as `window` and `document` actually have to be implemented, just what they should implement.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb I'd just say for _host Objects_, check using `in`, for _native objects_ (esp. `instanceof`s), check using `hasOwnProperty`. If you want to know the difference; http://stackoverflow.com/a/7614380/1615483

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does HTML standard specify which properties of a document should be direct and can be reliably tested with hasOwnProperty()

Yes, [WebIDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#es-attributes) does specify this. In your case, there should be a getter property (as [`pointerLockElement` is a readonly attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/pointerlock/#extensions-to-the-document-interface)) on the `document.prototype` (because it was not declared `[Unforgeable]`).

> or are all such tests implementation dependent and not portable?

However, I don't know whether all browsers do adhere that spec - certainly there are some that don't. Also, you're testing vendor extensions in your example (prefixed with `moz` or `webkit`) and I don't know whether their behaviour is specified at all. If you want to test against the prototypes, notice that [there are implementation differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21771768/1048572) as well.

So, your best bet is the `in` operator which detects all properties, regardless whether they're defined on the object itself or one of its prototypes. You might also try `!== undefined`, as nullable properties would return `null` instead of `undefined`.