# Accept ".jpg-large" in HTML5 input element

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, jpeg

When saving images from Twitter, then these images are sometimes saved with the extension `.jpg-large` when using Google Chrome ([Chromium Issue 172529](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=172529)).

I was wondering if it is still possible to select these images in the file explorer when chosing an image via an `input` element?

My input element is this:

```
<input 
  accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/bmp, image/gif"
  data-bind="file_select: upload_images" 
  multiple="multiple" 
  type="file"     
/>
```

I checked the MIME type of the `image-large` file and it is `image/jpeg`:

[image]

So the browser should be able to display it in the file dialog but in fact it's hidden:

[image]

Is there a way to display this custom file extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [HTML Living Standard by WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-input-accept) (not to be confused with W3C) the `accept` attribute is not restricted to MIME types—it'll also accept file extensions:

> **A string whose first character is a U+002E FULL STOP character (.)**
>       Indicates that files with the specified file extension are accepted.

In your case:

```
<input 
  accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/bmp,image/gif,.jpg-large"
  data-bind="file_select: upload_images" 
  multiple="multiple" 
  type="file"     
/>
```

I've used it myself and I can tell you all major browsers support it, though user interface varies (I particularly find Firefox's implementation cleaner).

*Please note that OS file chooser will normally filter by file extension, it won't inspect actual file contents to guess the MIME type—at least on desktop computers.*

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you have a code sample for using a "file extension" in "accept"?

Comment: Works for me in Chrome 50. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible.  The [specification says that you can only define by MIME type](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html).  So there's no way of saying e.g. "*.jpeg-large".

In *theory*, the OS should know the file type without resorting to sniffing file extensions.

That's how it works on Android.  A file saved with `.jpeg-large` is able to be selected when used with `accept="image/*"`

Comment: I always get lost in the sea of drafts, recommendations and working documents... but your document is from May 2013. Is it current standard?

Comment: W3C allows only MIME types (https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html#input.file.attrs.accept) and WHATWG allows MIME types and file extensions (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-input-accept). Choose your weapon! :D

Comment: Yes, of course... They are different organisations thus they produce different documents... I found this: [W3C vs WHATWG. Which gives the most authoritative spec?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825713/html5-w3c-vs-whatwg-which-gives-the-most-authoritative-spec). Thank you!