# Body's background is overflowing

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i have set my body's height and width to be 100px each and given it a background color of Red and border of 10px solid black. Why instead of 100x100 red box with a black border, i see Red color all over the screen with the border having expected dimenstions.

```css
html, body{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

body{
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 60px;
    border:10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is weird. That's not what I would have expected, but [this](https://css-tricks.com/just-one-of-those-weird-things-about-css-background-on-body/) seems to indicate it's a known behavior, that if the background color on `<html>` isn't set, but the background color on `<body>` is, the `<body>` background will flood the whole `<html>` area.

To quote [the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#ref-for-propdef-background-color%E2%91%A6):

> For documents whose root element is an HTML HTML element or an XHTML
> html element [HTML]: if the computed value of background-image on the
> root element is none and its background-color is transparent, user
> agents must instead propagate the computed values of the background
> properties from that element’s first HTML BODY or XHTML body child
> element. The used values of that BODY element’s background properties
> are their initial values, and the propagated values are treated as if
> they were specified on the root element.

You can also see an example at that spec link that is similar to yours.

### UPDATE:

RE: your other question about `<html>` element's propagating to the viewport's background, I think that is also answered [in a nearby section of the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#special-backgrounds), though it is a little less clear to me:

> The background of the root element becomes the canvas background and
> its background painting area extends to cover the entire canvas.

Note `canvas` in this case refers to the infinite surface the page is rendered on, not the HTML5 canvas. This seems to me to describe the behavior you mentioned in a comment where the background of a `<html>` with a small width/height is propagated to the viewport, though why they need the additional section I quoted above, I'm not sure about. There is more info at that link if you are curious. There seems to be some overlap between sections AFAICT.

Comment: yes indeed the body's background is propogating to html but now the same issue is with html. 
 i have set 100x100px height and width dimensions with 10 px black border. instead of seeing a 100x100px blue box, the background is overflowing all over the screen with the border having expected demenstions. `body, html{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
} html{
    background-color: aqua;
    border:10px solid black;
}``body{
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 60px;
    border:10px solid black;
}`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you need to make the html and body elements both smaller than the browser viewport?

Comment: well i was just trying to see the body's border but bumped into this behaviour

Comment: I'm certainly not a spec expert, but best I can tell that behavior is also covered in that area of the spec. Updated my answer.

Comment: thanks hope it's a reliable source

Comment: Well, they use the specs as reference for writing the browsers. Though I'm a little fuzzy about the [difference between WHATWG Specs and W3C specs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34984276/356887) (I couldn't find a WHATWG CSS one for this answer, just the W3C one). Looking at the spec is about as reliable as you can get apart from reading the code of the various browsers. Though reading them is kindof a headache and certainly the browsers don't *have* to implement everything as described...

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to create a 100x100 red box with a black border, you can create a div in your html and then give the div the properties you want in your CSS.

For example,

```css
.red-box {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color: red;
    border:10px solid black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class = "red-box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```